# how can i use variables in a if statement and out of it?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I const a variable in an if statement but I can't use the variable out of the statement

```js
const a = 1

const b = 1

if (a == b) {
  const c = 1
  console.log(c)
}
console.log(c)
```

fist it gives me c ( in the if statement) then it gives me an error(out of the if statement)

Comment: that's because [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) has blocked-scope, you can declare it as `var` or declare it outside the `if` initially using `let`, and then initialize it within the `if`

Comment: It's indeed block scoped. Meaning; it's not accessible outside of the `{ }`. If you want to do something inside the if statement you can use `let` outside the if and reassign the value in the condition statement

Answer (score 2):

you could either declare it before with let and change its value later on:

```
const a = 1
const b = 1
let c;

if (a == b ){
    c = 1
}
console.log(c)
```

or write a function that returns a value based on the other const.

```
const a = 1
const b = 1
let c = myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  if (a == b ){
    return 1
  }
}
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `let, const` uses block scoping + those are special types that **does not get hoisted**. 
Here, you are trying to access `'c'` which is not available in scope and you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are declaring `c` inside if condition it wont be accessible out of `if` and also you cannot make c as `const` ,because you have to assign a value when you declare a `const` variable and hence you cannot change again `c` inside 'if'

```js
const a = 1
const b = 1
var c=1;
if (a == b ){
    c = 1
    console.log(c)    
}
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just because It's `scope`, In this case, `c` is available into `if` block only If you want it outside then you need to declare `c` with `let`

```js
const a = 1;

const b = 1
let c = null;

if (a === b) {
    c = 1;
    console.log(c);
}
   console.log(c);
```